# SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, replit

```
class Match {
  JSDOM = jsdom;
  Discord = require("discord.js");
  jsdom = require("jsdom");
  …
}
```

This is the code I use, and I get the error:

```
JSDOM = jsdom();
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Why? This should work right? This only happens when I try to run the code on repl.it. When I run it on my computer it works fine.

Comment: It would only work with a Babel-ish/JS version that supports it; repl.it, in the setup you're using, does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone wondering, I found the problem. I was importing the project from GitHub, when I made a new REPL and specified node.js as the language, then imported the files, everything worked as expected.